# PHP error_log file

Tags: error-handling, php, eaccelerator

Can anyone help me with error_log file. If you already guessed that I am not experienced user, that is true :-)

I have VPS on CentOS 5 with 4 CPU and 768 memory. With 5 sites on it.

Problem I have is that, no meter on which site system generate file "error_log" in root of sites, and in any other folder where there is any php script, so after running some php script there is error_log in that folder.

On every access system writes new lines, and it is the same error message, in any error file just time in different.

This is part of error_log file:

```
[13-Mar-2012 06:52:18] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/eaccelerator.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/eaccelerator.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[13-Mar-2012 06:52:20] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/eaccelerator.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/eaccelerator.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
```

If I am right it is something about eaccelerator or something. I tried to find what is that, and it is some caching mechanism, if I am right. So far I know I did not do anything with that.

My sites are using widely used static html cache, ones page is generated by php it is stored in text file on disk and after server from disk. Something like this: [http://www.theukwebdesigncompany.com/articles/php-caching.php][1]

Any help to find problem, and to fix it would be nice. Also if you have any question, do not hesitate to ask, I will try to help as much as I can. Again, I am not experienced with WHM, so If you ask me something please tell me where exactly to look for it :-).

Best regards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must install eAccelerator extension for php 5.3
you maybe updated to php 5.3 and forgot to install it (or cp auto update !)

eAccelerator is a free open source PHP accelerator, optimizer, encoder and
dynamic content cache for PHP. It increases performance of PHP scripts by 
caching them in compiled state, so that the overhead of compiling is almost
completely eliminated. Also it uses some optimizations to speed up execution
of PHP scripts. eAccelerator typically reduces server load and increases the
speed of your PHP code by 1-10 times.

gogole about it to install or use this link http://www.dedicated-resources.com/guide/128/eAccelerator-for-PHP.html

if you can not do that or dont want to install ir, you can edit /usr/local/lib/php.ini and remove eaccelerator.so, pdo.so, pdo_sqlite.so, sqlite.so in extension section
or back to php 5.2

i recommend to you to install eAccelerator and boost your php performance ;)